# QGIS python for generating TIFF images from LAT/LON

Tags: pyqgis, image

I am new to PyQGIS, looking for help with the following.  I included some pseudo-code at the bottom.

1. Read a CSV file with records having these fields: `Longitude1, Latitude1, Longitude2, Latitude2, scale, dpi, tifFilename, marginXmm, marginYmm`
2. For each record: generate a TIFF image file to tifFilename. e.g. "c:\temp\myFile.tif".  The image will have a specific scale and DPI.  Like the "export map to image" dialog.  But the extents, scale and resolution are read from the CSV file.
3. For each record: generate a 2nd TIFF image file to [tifFilename + "-margin"]. E.g. "c:\temp\myFile-margin.tif".
   Image2 will be the same scale and DPI and have the same center as image1.  But it will be larger than image1, covering more map area.
   E.g. if image1 is 100mm x 200mm, marginXmm=3mm, marginYmm=5mm: image2 will be 106mm x 210mm.  100+3+3, 200+5+5.  See below.

Pseudo-code:

```
for each record in csv-file:
    read Longitude1, Latitude1, Longitude2, Latitude2, scale, dpi, tifFilename, marginXmm, marginYmm
    # make image1
    rectangle1 = convertTo4326 (Longitude1, Latitude1, Longitude2, Latitude2)  
        # not sure what conversion is needed
        # e.g. convertTo4326 (-130, 45, -110, 50)  covers WA state 
    extent1 = rectToExtent (rectangle1)
    image1 = makeImageFile (extent1, scale, dpi, tifFilename, "tif")  # parameters like in dialog "export map to image"
    outputWidth1 = getWidthFrom(image1)   # in mm
    outputHeight1 = getHeightFrom(image1)
    
    # make image2 
    deltaX = (scale * marginXmm / 1000)  # get the extra 'margin' for larger map, in meters
    deltaY = (scale * marginYmm / 1000)
    xMin = rectangle1.xMin - deltaX
    yMin = rectangle1.yMin - deltaY
    xMax = rectangle1.xMax + deltaX
    yMax = rectangle1.yMax + deltaY
    rectangle2 = pointsToRect(xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax)
    extent2 = rectToExtent (rectangle2)
    image2 = makeImageFile (extent2, scale, dpi, (tifFilename + "-margin"), "tif")
    # check: outputWidth2 = outputWidth1 + 2*marginXmm;  outputHeight2 = outputHeight1 + 2*marginYmm
```

[image: "export map to image" dialog]

Comment: what do you want stored in the TIFF file? Is it a blank file, or are you trying to automate saving portions of the current map?

Comment: The TIFF file would store the image of the map. 
So the pseudocode  

`image1 = makeImageFile (extent1, scale, dpi, tifFilename, "tif")`
might translate to something like
`canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()`
`canvas.setExtent(extent1)`
`# need to set DPI, scale...`
`canvas.saveAsImage("c:\temp\myFile.tif",None ,"TIF")
`

Comment: so yes,  trying to automate saving portions of the map, those portions (extents) defined in the csv file

Answer (score 0):

I did a bunch of copy pasting from other posts.
It works but I am still fuzzy on DPI / scale.  For example
`mapSettings.setOutputDpi(300)`: this does not change the output DPI, so what is it for?
`img.setDotsPerMeterX()`:  I could not find this in the PyQGIS API.  Is there a new better way?

Here is the working code, minus the 2nd larger TIFF and the part for reading the CSV file and iterating over all records:

```
# create image
img = QImage(QSize(1800, 600), QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
# set dpi
dpmeter = 11811  # 300 dpi
img.setDotsPerMeterX(dpmeter)
img.setDotsPerMeterY(dpmeter)    
# set image's background color
color = QColor(255, 255, 255)
img.fill(color.rgb())

# create painter
p = QPainter()
p.begin(img)
p.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

# first create the map settings, then pass to a renderer
mapSettings = QgsMapSettings()

# set dpi - first try
mapSettings.setOutputDpi(300)  # does not change the output dpi so what is this for?
    # img.setDotsPerMeterX(dpmeter)  this does the job

# set layer set
vlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("myLayer")[0]
mapSettings.setLayers([vlayer])  # this takes a list of QgsMapLayer as input

# set extent
r_min = QgsPointXY(-130,45)  # longitude, latitude
r_max = QgsPointXY(-110,50)
rect = QgsRectangle(r_min, r_max) # WA state roughly
src_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)
dest_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(3857)
xform = QgsCoordinateTransform(src_crs, dest_crs, QgsProject().instance())
rect = xform.transform(rect)
mapSettings.setExtent(rect) 

# set output size
mapSettings.setOutputSize(img.size()) 

# do the rendering
render = QgsMapRendererCustomPainterJob(mapSettings, p) # takes the settings and painter as parameters
render.start()             # rendering is now asynchronous, so you could use threads here
render.waitForFinished()   # but we will block until it's finished
    # without waitForFinished() the output image is blank/white
p.end()

# save image
img.save("c:/temp/wa_state.tif","tif")  # note windows fwd not backslash \
```

Comment: I will post again when I have the rest working:  


1. Reading parameters from csv file  


2. Generating the 2nd larger TIFF image with `marginXmm` and `marginYmm`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).